# shell prog bash loop for printing

Tags: shell

I have a input file (input.txt) that contains

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

I have a output file(output.txt) that has

```
a.txt Passed
b.txt Failed
```

I want a script that find.sh input.txt output.txt that displays all the entries that do not pass and are there in input.txt ie 
b.txt
c.txt

I tried the following but was getting a if: Expression Syntax. error

```
#!/bin/csh -f

foreach line (`cat $1`)
  grep "$line" $2 | grep Failed
  if [ 'grep $line $2' -eq 0 ]
   then
    echo "$line"
  fi
end
```

Comment: _I want a script_. OK, show us any code you managed to create yourself then we'd be able to help.

Comment: #!/bin/csh -f

foreach line (`cat $1`)
  #grep "$line" $2 | grep Passed
  if [ 'grep $line $2' -eq 0 ]
   then 
    echo "$line"
  fi
end ; I get an error if: Expression Syntax.

Comment: please add this to your question so people can read it and answer your question. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT_FILE="$1"
OUTPUT_FILE="$2"

for filename in "$(grep ' Failed' $OUTPUT_FILE | sed 's/ Failed//')"
do
    grep "$filename" "$INPUT_FILE"
done
```

input.txt:

```
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

output.txt:

```
a.txt Passed
b.txt Failed
```

result:

```
dino@dam2knb:/tmp$ ./find.sh input.txt output.txt 
b.txt
```

Comment: i want the output all files other than those passed in the output.txt

Answer (score 0):

cm1@ip10 /remote > cat failed.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cat $1 | while read line
do
  grep "$line" $2 | grep Failed
  if ! grep -q "$line" $2; then
    echo "$line"
  fi
done
```